# Regex for email validation with separator

Tags: regex, typescript, email-validation

I am trying to achive regex expression:
I need regex with email, I am using that:

```
\S+@\S+\.\S+
```

And I want to repreat it X times with  `;` separator.
I cant figure this out...
For example pattern should allow following strings:

```
example1@email.com
example1@email.com;example2@email.com;example3@email.com;example4@email.com
```

But should not allow for example following string:

```
example1@email.com;example2email.com;example3@email.com;
```

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the X-separated list of entities is matched with `^y(?:Xy)*$` like pattern.

Here, there is a caveat related to what you match with `y` and `X`: `\S` matches `;` chars, so the semi-colon has to be "removed" from the `\S` pattern, hence the `\S` should be replaced with `[^\s;]` in the resulting pattern.

You can use

```
^[^\s;]+@[^\s;]+\.[^\s;]+(?:;[^\s;]+@[^\s;]+\.[^\s;]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fpfqin/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\s;]+@[^\s;]+\.[^\s;]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace and `;`, `@`, one or more chars other than whitespace and `;`, `.` and then again one or more chars other than whitespace and `;`
- `(?:` - start of a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/3832970):

  - `;` - a semi-colon
  - `[^\s;]+@[^\s;]+\.[^\s;]+` - email-like pattern (described above)
- `)*` - end of the non-capturing group, repeat zero or more occurrences
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks! Generally works but now I can pass emails with strange character, for example: dasdasd+sds@wp.pl

Comment: @zxf18682 In the [same way](https://regex101.com/r/Fpfqin/2).

Comment: dasdasd+sds@wp.pl should not be passed and other characters like (,),* etc. that should not contain in email

Comment: @zxf18682 You need to define the rules for the user, domain and TLD parts of the regex. This is out of scope of the current question. There are a lot of email validation regex questions on SO, please use the site search.